# Convert the word using uppercase

Tags: javascript, regex, string

```
let header=myWordDDam.
```

convert above word into output="My Word DDam".

Tried using regex

```
let output=header.replace(/^./, header[0].toUpperCase()).split(/(?=[A-Z])/).join(" ");
```

But output is "My Word D Dam"
Stuck using if there is consecutive Uppercase. If there is consecutive uppercase it should not append space only if there is one uppercase in between word space should be apply

Comment: `const magicFunction = (input) => "My Word DDam"`

Comment: If you want more than that you'll need to give us more info on the nature of what you're trying to do and what problem you're running into. You may want to check out [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: `header.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + header.substring(1).replace(/(?!^)[A-Z]+/g,' $&')`

Comment: @coreyward This is not a bad question. It contains the input, the expected output and the tried code.

Comment: I am rendering grid data.Often grid data header comes in format abcXyz, abcXYZ.For better user representation i need to convert to above format

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew u rock man!

Comment: @GauthamShetty I added the solution [as an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52708269/3832970) with all explanations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.split(/(?=[A-Z])/).join(" ")` part matches all locations in a string that are followed with an uppercase letter, and thus spaces are added before each of them.

You need to consume chunks of 1+ uppercase letters and add a space before those whole chunks.

Thus, to fix your current approach, you may replace the `.split(/(?=[A-Z])/).join(" ")` with  `.replace(/(?!^)[A-Z]+/g,' $&')`.

```js
let header = "myWordDDam";
let output = header.replace(/^./, m => m.toUpperCase()).replace(/(?!^)[A-Z]+/g,' $&')
console.log(output);
```

**Details**

- `.replace(/^./, m => m.toUpperCase())` - `^.` matches the first char and converts it to upper case
- `.replace(/(?!^)[A-Z]+/g,' $&')` - matches any 1+ uppercase ASCII letters (with `[A-Z]+`) (not at the start of the string - `(?!^)`) and the text is replaced with a space + the whole match (`$&`).